# Adding sub directories to Android Studio Assets File system

Tags: android, android-studio

I have noticed that on Ubuntu with AS, if you manually add a directory to the src/main/assets folder it triggers the infamous "cannot resolve symbol R" error. For example: I tried to add an index.html along with it's css/ and js/ dir and files and my R.layout and R.id arguments started getting the red highlighting.

Upon deleting the newly added directories and leaving the index.html and thus rebuilding the project to clean it, the error went away.

My questions are: why, and is there a safe way to "import" directories into the assets folder in my project with things going completely crackers in AS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the project actually build correctly even though it's showing errors in the editor windows? If not, what's the error you're getting?

Comment: No, the project does not build correctly. Only one error comes back and it is the "can not resolve symbol R" error. These seems to be an issue on Ubuntu. When i manually imported the files on my Mac, there was no issue. Did anyone else have a different experience on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, looks like a bug in AS 0.43 when using Ubuntu. Recommend upgrading to 0.53 and hoping for the best, or don't use AS until it reaches 1.0. Hooray for testing preview software!